# BaseSite styles developed by us is not showing up in Spartacus frontend, any idea why?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am a frontend developer, working first time on Spartacus. I am told to convert a hybris commerce site into Spartacus. The site is fully custom styled. I installed Spartacus and imported the same as basesite. But all styles are not showing up at localhost:4200. It shows the theme of the electronic site. I have followed the step as per Spartacus documentation. Any idea what is missing from my side?

Comment: I'm not sure where the "BaseSite styles" are added. Did you stored them inside your angular application (`styles.scss`?).


Angular uses global styles (i.e. `styles.css` which can be futher customised in the `angular.json`) and component specific styles. I'd expect you to bring in your styles in the `style.css` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use schematics, after generate project you should have yourProject/src/styles.scss, there is default imported barrel styles from spartacus library.
You can add global styles to this file and also import other style files. Above or instead.